# Python - how can i make the client to be able to connect multiple times?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, python-2.7, ubuntu

When i use client1 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.2', '3') only it works but when i use both as below:
client1 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.2', '3')
client2 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.3', '3')

then the whole thing become like very slow and sometimes one of them fails. How to make sure that client1 and client2 connects + sends + faster enough?

```
import asyncore, socket

class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, host, path):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.settimeout(10)
    try:
      self.connect( (host, 8888) )
    except:
      print 'unable to connect'
      pass
    self.buffer = path

  def handle_connect(self):
    pass

  def handle_close(self):
    self.close()

  def handle_read(self):
    print self.recv(8192)

  def writable(self):
    return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

  def handle_write(self):
    sent = self.send(self.buffer)
    self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


client1 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.2', '3')
client2 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.3', '3')
asyncore.loop()
```

**EDIT:** tried also threading but same result

```
import asyncore, socket
import threading
import os

class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, host, path):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.settimeout(10)
    try:
      self.connect( (host, 8888) )
    except:
      print 'unable to connect'
      pass
    self.buffer = path

  def handle_connect(self):
    pass

  def handle_close(self):
    self.close()

  def handle_read(self):
    print self.recv(8192)

  def writable(self):
    return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

  def handle_write(self):
    sent = self.send(self.buffer)
    self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]

def t1():
  client1 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.161', '3')  

def t2():
  client2 = HTTPClient('192.168.1.163', '3')

t0 = threading.Thread(target=t1())
t0.start()
t0.join() 

t0 = threading.Thread(target=t2())
t0.start()
t0.join() 

asyncore.loop()
```

Comment: can you describe in more detail what you mean by "becomes very slow and sometimes one of them fails"? in what way does it fail?

Comment: When you use client1 only to connect it works perfect. But when you use client 1 and client 2 to connect it takes more then normal timeout as a result the connection fails and the total trip become abnormal compared to single connect.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t0` and `t1`, and `t0.start()`, `t1.start()` and only then the joins? Right now you're starting the threads one after the other, not simultaneously.

Comment: YES - changed t0 and t1 it was typo. but still same problem it takes while same like without threading . Any more ideas!

Comment: And for the joins? Right now it looks like "starting thread 1", waiting for it to stop", starting thread 2", "waiting for it to stop". It has no chance to run faster if you don't wait for the first one to stop before launching the second one.

Comment: How can i do it like not waiting for the thread 1 to complete like you explain?

Comment: I don't think it's the solution to your problem anyway, so I'm not putting it in an answer, but the `join` method is **waiting for your thread to stop**. So by calling it, you block your main thread, which can't create and start the second thread until the first is finished. Don't call any `join` before starting both thread, or else it's completely useless. But as I said, I don't think it's the solution. `t1` and `t2` only create the clients, `asyncore.loop()` is still called from the main thread.

Comment: cant u twistedpython :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several issues in your code e.g., drop parentheses when you are specifying a target: `Thread(target=t1)`. If `f` is a function then `f()` calls it immediately. You are also mixing `asyncore` with blocking code and multiple threads.

If you want to make several http connections concurrently; you could use a thread pool instead:

```
import urllib2
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

def fetch(url):
    try:
        return url, urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), None
    except Exception as e:
        return url, None, str(e)

urls = ['http://example.com', ...]
pool = Pool(20) # use no more than 20 concurrent connections
for url, result, error in pool.imap_unordered(fetch, urls):
    if error is None:
       print(url + " done")
    else:
       print(url + " error: " + error)
```

Answer (score 1):

The connect method of your HTTPClient is blocking, if your 2nd host doesn't except the connection, your try/except block is exciting after the timeout. Your except block isn't closing the socket so acynscore.loop() is still waiting for it.

Try my modifications below and see if they confirm the problem.  I've put some print statements around the connect method to illustrate the blocking portion of the code and I've explicitly closed the socket in the except.  It would also be helpful if you could post your server code, as I expect the problem is there.  If the server code is outside your control, you code shorten your time out to something much smaller and open your connections some kind of loop, but you should back off your connection attempts each iteration (wait 1 second, then 2 then 4 then 8, etc between connection attempts).

```
import asyncore, socket
import time

class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, host, path):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.HOST = host
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.settimeout(10)
    try:
      t0 = time.time()
      print "connecting to host:", host, '...blocking...'
      self.connect( (host, 80) )
      print "connected to host (%s) in %0.2f seconds:"%(host, time.time()-t0)
    except:
      print 'unable to connect'
      self.close()
    self.buffer = path

  def handle_connect(self):
    pass

  def handle_close(self):
    self.close()

  def handle_read(self):
    print self.recv(8192)

  def writable(self):
    return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

  def handle_write(self):
    sent = self.send(self.buffer)
    self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]


client1 = HTTPClient('news.google.com', 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
client2 = HTTPClient('not_a_valid_server.local', 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
client3 = HTTPClient('news.yahoo.com', 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
asyncore.loop()
```